# JavaFX + Scene Builder Update Label with choicebox

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm wondering the best way to update a Label from a ChoiceBox value
As of right now I have the label updating on clicking the ChoiceBox, but this makes the user select a choice and then click the ChoiceBox to update
Here is the relevant code for a display method I call on mouse click to the choicebox in Scene Builder

```
  @FXML
public void display() {
    label.setText((String) stockChoice.getValue());
}
```

also, my initialize method in which I put an item (lettuce) into the choicebox

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    modelClass = new WarehouseModel();
    modelClass.addNewVariety("Lettuce");
    stockChoice.getItems().addAll(modelClass.getAllVarieties());

}
```

Thank you in advance for all help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of methods to do this, but personally I would use a simple binding.

```
label.textProperty().bind(stockChoice.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());
```

That is assuming `stockChoice` is a `ChoiceBox` of `String` items. If the item is a custom type, then you can use `Bindings.createStringBinding()` to help you.

Comment: Awesome! That worked perfectly, thank you for the quick response!